# How to connect mongodb using Springboot through mongoose?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have already done connect MongoDB using application.properties. But I want to connect MongoDB through mongoose.

This is my current configuration

This is DB Connection url setting in application.properties;

```
    spring.data.mongodb.uri =mongodb+srv://hans123:Hans123@cluster0.avxi858.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

spring.data.mongodb.database=test

spring.data.mongodb.port=27017

spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Class

```
@Document
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @Indexed
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String address;
    @Indexed
    private String name;
    @Indexed
    private String email;
    @Indexed
    private String password;
    @Indexed
    private String role;
}
```

Repository Class

```
public interface userReporsitory extends MongoRepository<User,String> {
    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
    List<User> findAllByRole(String role);
}
```

Service Class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class userService {
    private userReporsitory userReporsitory;
    public User saveUser(User user){
        return userReporsitory.save(user);    
    }
    public User login(User user){
          User response = userReporsitory.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).orElseThrow(()->new RuntimeException("User Not Found"));
          
          if(!response.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword())){
            throw new RuntimeException("Bad Credincials");
          }

          return response;
    }

    public List<User> findAllUsers(){
      return userReporsitory.findAllByRole("user");
    }
}
```

Controller Class

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("api/v1/user")
public class userController {
   private userService userService;

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<User> save(@RequestBody User user){
        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED;
        User response = userService.saveUser(user);

        if(response != null){
           status = HttpStatus.CREATED;
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, status);
        
    }
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<User> login(@RequestBody User user){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.login(user),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        
    }
    @GetMapping("/userList")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> userList(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.findAllUsers(),HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
        

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In above answer you can encrypt the password as well (Additional Thing)
AuthRequest Class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthRequestDto {
    private String userName;
    private String password;
}
```

RegisterRequest Class:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegisterRequestDto {

    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

}
```

UserService Class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final JWTUtility jwtUtility;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException("user name not found"));
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userEntity.getRole());
        return new User(userEntity.getUsername() , userEntity.getPassword() , new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(authority)));
    }

    public UserEntity registerUser(RegisterRequestDto request){

        //check user is already in
        if(userRepository.existsByUsernameIgnoreCase(request.getUserName())){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("user name already exist in the system");
        }

        if(userRepository.existsByEmailIgnoreCase(request.getEmail())){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("email already exist in the system");
        }

        UserEntity saveToBe = UserEntity.builder()
                                        .username(request.getUserName())
                                        .password(new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(request.getPassword()))
                                        .firstName(request.getFirstName())
                                        .email(request.getEmail())
                                        .phone((request.getPhone()))
                                        .address(request.getAddress())
                                        .role(Role.BUYER)
                                        .build();

        return userRepository.save(saveToBe);
    }

    public AuthRespondDto loginUser(AuthRequestDto authRequestDto){

        final UserDetails userDetails = loadUserByUsername(authRequestDto.getUserName());
        final String token = jwtUtility.generateToken(userDetails);
        return new AuthRespondDto(token , authRequestDto.getUserName() , userDetails.getAuthorities().stream().findFirst().get().getAuthority());
    }

    public long getAuthUserId(String username){
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        return userEntity.getId();
    }

    public String getUserAddressByName(String username){
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        return userEntity.getAddress();
    }

    public String getUserPhoneByName(String username){
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        return userEntity.getPhone();
    }

    public String getUserEmailByName(String username){
        UserEntity userEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username).get();
        return userEntity.getEmail();
    }

    public UserEntity getUserById(long id){
        return userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()-> new NotFoundException("user not found"));
    }
}
```

AuthController Class (Controller Class):

```
public class AuthController {


    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthRespondDto> login(@RequestBody AuthRequestDto authRequestDto) throws BadCredentialsException {

        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            authRequestDto.getUserName(),
                            authRequestDto.getPassword()
                    )
            );
        }catch (BadCredentialsException e){
            //TODO add proper exception
            throw new BadCredentialsException("INVALID_USERNAME_OR_PASSWORD" , e);
        }


        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.loginUser(authRequestDto) , HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }


    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<UserEntity> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequestDto request){
        // basic controller level validations
        if(request.getUserName().isEmpty()){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("user name is required");
        }
        if(request.getPassword().isEmpty()){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("password is required");
        }
        if(request.getFirstName().isEmpty()){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("first name is required");
        }
        if(request.getEmail().isEmpty()){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("email is required");
        }
        if(request.getPhone().isEmpty()){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("phone is required");
        }
        if(request.getPhone().length() != 10){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("phone number length must be 10");
        }
        if(request.getAddress().isEmpty()){
            throw new FieldValidationFaild("address is required");
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.registerUser(request) , HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }

}
```